# Install the IIS ASP.NET Core module via Powershell

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

In a continuous deployment scenario I'm trying to deploy a .Net core web application on IIS starting from a clean machine. During the automated tasks I download and execute the [dotnet-install.ps1](https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1) script that is responsible of installing the .Net runtime in the user's `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\dotnet` folder.

Now I need to provide IIS with the `AspNet Core Module` that allows it to run .Net core applications, but I found that the only way to install it is to download the .Net core runtime from the official web site and install it.

Instead, what I would like to do is to preserve the way I install the .Net core runtime via the `dotnet-install.ps1` script (which automatically checks for upgrades and handles all the installation) while being able to install only the IIS AspNet Core Module.

Is there any installation method to support me installing only the IIS AspNet core module?

Thanks

Comment: Good question. What I also noticed is if your doing a clean install the environment variables are set and you need to handle also a restart for them to apply. [Maybe this can help you further](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script)

Comment: You probably should try to write your own script or use Chocolatey  to simplify your process, https://chocolatey.org/packages/dotnetcore-windowshosting/2.2.3

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan regarding the environment variables, the script sets the path to the `dotnet` executable only for the current PS session, but then it is needed to add it to the $env:Path variable permanently by yourself

Comment: @LexLi I will investigate about Chocolatey, but I was searching for a solution with less tools and external dependencies as possible

Answer (score 0):

Now we have a new way to install .NET runtime on later versions of Windows.
This command will do that:
`winget install Microsoft.DotNet.AspNetCore.6`

There is a built-in command called `winget`

You can run from the CLI to install the typical dotnet windows runtimes and sdks

- `winget install Microsoft.DotNet.runtime.6`
- `winget install Microsoft.DotNet.AspNetCore.6`
- `winget install Microsoft.DotNet.DesktopRuntime`
- `winget install Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.6`

This downloads the graphical installers and runs them for you.
If you don't want to see any installers with `winget` you can use the `--silent` or -h command line switch stop display of the progress window.  It should be noted that all `winget` packages don't always conform and silent is ignored by some, but your should be safe with packages from Microsoft.